# How to call method in setup of vuejs3 app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In vuejs3 app I retrieve data from db with axios in method, like :

```
<script>
  import appMixin from '@/appMixin'
  import app from './../../App.vue' // eslint-disable-line
  import axios from 'axios'

  const emitter = mitt()

  export default {
    name: 'adminCategoriesList',
    mixins: [appMixin],
    data: function () {
      return {
        categoriesPerPage: 20,
        currentPage: 1,
        categoriesTotalCount: 0,
        categories: []
      }
    },

    components: {
    },
    setup () {
      const adminCategoriesListInit = async () => {
        this.loadCategories() // ERROR HERE
      }

      function onSubmit (credentials) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(credentials, null, 2))
        console.log('this::')
        console.log(this)
        console.log('app::')
      }

      onMounted(adminCategoriesListInit)

      return {
        // schema,
        onSubmit
      }
    }, // setup

    methods: {
      loadCategories() {
        ...
      }
```

and I got error in browser's console :

```
Cannot read property 'loadCategories' of undefined
```

If to remove “this.” in loadCategories call
I got error :

```
'loadCategories' is not defined
```

I need to make loadCategories as method, as I need to cal;l it from different places.

Which way is correct ?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to return the method `loadCategories` from the `setup`. Also, I'd suggest doing either full Composition API or Options API -- but not both.

Comment: I prefer Composition API , but in which way ? What is wrong in my structure now?

Comment: Well, try placing the method inside the `setup` callback and return it from there. That allows you to access it as well as expose it on the template (once returned).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use composition and options api in the same component but for different properties and methods, in your case the data properties could be defined inside `setup` hook using [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref) or [`reactive`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive), the methods could be defined as plain js functions :

```js
import {ref} from 'vue'
export default {
  name: 'adminCategoriesList',
  mixins: [appMixin],
  components: {
  },
  setup () {
    const categoriesPerPage= ref(20);
    const currentPage=ref(1);
    const categoriesTotalCount=ref(0),
    const categories=ref[])

    const adminCategoriesListInit = async () => {
      loadCategories()
    }

    function onSubmit (credentials) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(credentials, null, 2))
    }

    functions loadCategories(){
      ...
    }

    onMounted(adminCategoriesListInit)

    return {
      // schema,
      onSubmit,
      categoriesPerPage,
      currentPage,
      categoriesTotalCount,
      categories
    }
  },
```

the properties defined by `ref` could be used/mutated by `property.value` and used in template like `{{property}}`

Comment: Thanks! Please more details about ref with link where it is described ?

Comment: you're welcome, i added the link to the official docs, and watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qypxpm-llnQ)